# All lines printing fine but getting out of bound error

Tags: java

I have a string array that contains three lines of information below for three columns username, password and accesstype:

`String allUsers = "ckent 0123456789 u 
                    avril 0123456789 u 
                    jlati 0123456789 a"`

All though I can loop through the array and print out all the information, I am still getting an error `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 76`

Below is my code:

```
String[] usersArray = allUsers.split(" ");

for (int x = 0; x < usersArray.length-1; x++){

    //gets all user information per line.                    
    String userList = allUsers.substring(0+(19*x), 19+(19*x));

    //gets only the username for all three users                             
    String username = userList.substring(0,5);

    //gets only the password for all three users
    String password = allUsers.substring(6+(19*x),16+(19*x));

    //gets only the access type for all three users
    String accesstype = allUsers.substring(17+(19*x),19+(19*x));

    System.out.print(x);                            
    System.out.println(userList);


}
```

Is there another way I can do this and not get an OutOfBoundsError?

Comment: `String userList = allUsers.substring(0+(19*x), 19+(19*x));` -> `0+(19*x)` yelds `76` when `x = 4`. Why are you using substring with these indexes? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why do you use substring when you already split the array. What you might want to use are RegEx I think.

Comment: Your input string `allUsers` is in a bad format which makes it hard to extract individual components.  How did you end up with such data?

Comment: _contains three lines_, no, the code is on three line, but the String is on one line. You mind want to add `\n` in your String, from there, you could read each line, and split the line with `" " ` to get each field separated in an array. No substring needed.

Comment: @AxelH Actually we don't know that. Code with a string declared the way the OP wrote will not ever compile, so we don't really know how he is declaring it and if it really contains more lines or just one.

Comment: @BackSlash how yeah, didn't even notice they were not concatenated Strings on multiple line...

Answer (score 1):

You have a risky approach there. Since you have used `.split()`, you should know what it can do. If your input string is of this form (i assume that there is a space after those "u" (not clear at this moment)

```
String allUsers = "ckent 0123456789 u 
                   avril 0123456789 u 
                   jlati 0123456789 a"
```

you should use `.split(" ");` which you did. Now, if you use that method, you get an array of String elements. Here below is an example of the result if you do `allUsers.split(" ")`

```
[0] -> "ckent"
[1] -> "0123456789"
[2] -> "u"
[3] -> "avril"
[4] -> "0123456789"
[5] -> "u"
[6] -> "jlati"
[7] -> "0123456789"
[8] -> "a"
```

Do you see a pattern here? For each 3 steps, you have your data. Then it's a simple for loop (where `arr` is the above array):

```
for(int i = 0; (i + 2) < arr.length; i += 3) {
    String name = arr[i]; // i = 0, 3, 6
    String pw = arr[i+1]; // i = 1, 4, 7
    String access = arr[i+2]; // i = 2, 5, 8
}
```

The use of `i += 3` ensures that the for loop loops with 3 steps per loop. At the first loop, you have `i=0`, so

```
String name = arr[0]; // i = 0 -> gives "ckent"
String pw = arr[0+1]; // i = 1 -> gives "0123456789"
String access = arr[0+2]; // i = 2 -> gives "u"
```

Then at the end of the first loop, `i` becomes 3 because of `i += 3`. Hence you get a second loop because `(i + 2) < arr.length` is still true.

```
String name = arr[3]; // i = 3 -> gives "avril"
String pw = arr[3+1]; // i = 4 -> gives "0123456789"
String access = arr[3+2]; // i = 5 -> gives "u"
```

and so on until `(i + 2) < arr.length` becomes false.

Answer (score 0):

The `usersArray` will contain 9 entries. As BackSlash already wrote your code fails when `x` is more than 3.

Comment: But this doesn't answer the question. *Is there another way I can do this and not get an OutOfBoundsError?* - And honestly I don't think we can answer the question properly without knowing what the OP is trying to achieve first

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments. Maybe I should give a brief explanation of what I'm trying to achieve. I am reading the user information from a text file. When a user logs in, a logIn() function will check all users and match the username, password and the access type in the text file before a successful authentication. I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use substring again after splitting the string.

Hope below code snippet will be helpful:

```
 String allUsers = "ckent 0123456789 u avril 0123456789 u jlati 0123456789 a";

    String[] split = allUsers.split(" ");
    for (int i = -1; i < split.length - 3; ) {
        System.out.print(split[++i]);
        System.out.print(" "+split[++i]);
        System.out.print(" "+split[++i]);
        System.out.println();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments. Maybe I should give a brief explanation of what I'm trying to achieve. I am reading the user information from a text file. When a user logs in, a logIn() function will check all users and match the username, password and the access type in the text file before a successful authentication. I hope this is clear.